# Importing Request Session cookies to browser

Tags: python, session, cookies, python-requests

I am trying to get the cookies from a session with the requests module and import them into a browser to 'get a visual' on what's going on. I've played around with webdrivers but for sake of ease, I am using the Edit this cookie extension in chrome which has come in handy.

I have something like this.

```
import requests;
session=requests.Session();
session.cookies.clear();

url='http://www.mywebsite.com/login/;

data={'user': 'usernamehere',
    'password': 'passhere',
    'auth_token': 'tokenhere'
};
response=session.post(url,data=data);
print response.cookies
```

which returns something like:

```
<<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[Cookie(version=0, name='', value='', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='www.mywebsite.com',..., rest={}, rfc2109=False)]>
```

I was wondering how I could set this cookies or at least get it serialized. I've tried to dump with pickle and got an

```
is not JSON serializable
```

error. Is there any way I can either add to a webdriver or at least print it out in a prettier fashion.

Thank you

Comment: in which format you want them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`dict_from_cookiejar()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar) from the `requests.utils`:

```
from requests.utils import dict_from_cookiejar

cookies = dict_from_cookiejar(response.cookies)
```

Then, you can use [`add_cookie()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.add_cookie) to set the browser's cookies:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# set browser cookies
for key, value in cookies.items():
    driver.add_cookie({'name': key, 'value': value})  # TODO: may be "domain" would also be needed?
```